# Setting a meta table: Advantage of reference vs inline?

Tags: memory, lua, metatable

I was wondering if it would make sense to pass a meta table by reference vs declaring it in-line in `setmetatable()` when you want to use the same meta table for multiple tables.
My goal is to save memory, but only if it really makes a significant difference.

What I'm talking about is this:

```
-- Passing the meta table by reference: 
JSON1 = {
    metaTable = {
        __index = function (t, k)
            -- ...
        end;
        __call = function()
            -- ...
        end
    };
    parse = function(filePath)
        local fakeParsedJson = {}
        setmetatable(fakeParsedJson, JSON1.metaTable) -- Right here
        return fakeParsedJson(filePath)
    end;
}
```

**VS**

```
-- Passing the table in-line:
JSON2 = {
    parse = function(filePath)
        local fakeParsedJson = {}
        setmetatable(fakeParsedJson, { -- Right here:
            __index = function (t, k)
                -- ...
            end;
            __call = function()
                -- ...
            end
        })
        return fakeParsedJson(filePath)
    end;
}
```

I tried to find out if there is a significant difference in memory usage, but the only way I could find was to compare the gcinfo:

```
local start1 = gcinfo()
local example2_1 = JSON2.parse('example2_1.json')
local example2_2 = JSON2.parse('example2_2.json')
local example2_3 = JSON2.parse('example2_3.json')
local example2_4 = JSON2.parse('example2_4.json')
local example2_5 = JSON2.parse('example2_5.json')
print(gcinfo()-start1) -- Prints 1

local start2 = gcinfo()
local example1_1 = JSON1.parse('example1_1.json')
local example1_2 = JSON1.parse('example1_2.json')
local example1_3 = JSON1.parse('example1_3.json')
local example1_4 = JSON1.parse('example1_4.json')
local example1_5 = JSON1.parse('example1_5.json')
print(gcinfo()-start2) -- Prints 1
```

Here's my fiddle: https://repl.it/HfwS/34

It doesn't really look like there is a difference. But I just don't know what is actually happening under the hood.

When you call `setmetatable(myTable,myMetaTable)`, will that write a complete copy of `myMetaTable` somewhere into `myTable` or will it just store a simple reference? Because if it would just store a reference, then it would make a lot of sense to have all my tables pointing to the same meta table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(On `x86_64`, in Lua 5.3) every (empty) table costs 56 bytes.  Every key/value entry in the table costs 32 bytes (but the number of entries is rounded up to the next power of two).  (Byte counts may differ for different versions/platforms, but will be roughly the same +/- a power of two or so.)

If you have two entries in the metatable, that's 120 bytes per metatable.  (You're also creating closures (`function() … end`), so it may actually be even more.)

Having the table constructor in argument position for the call to `setmetatable` means that *every time that call is executed, a new independent table is created* (+ new closures for the `function`s, …).  (Also read [the section on table constructors](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.9) in the reference manual.) There is no smart compiler / no de-duplication / … In fact, there can't be, because other code could (potentially) modify a metatable, and then there's a clear semantic / observable difference between a single shared metatable and one metatable per thing.  If that's not obvious, compare

```
Foo = { __name = "Foo", dump = print } ; Foo.__index = Foo
function newFoo( )  return setmetatable( { }, Foo )  end
```

and

```
function newFoo( )
    local mt = { __name = "Foo", dump = print }
    mt.__index = mt
    return setmetatable( { }, mt )
end
```

If you say

```
t = { newFoo( ), newFoo( ), newFoo( ) }
getmetatable( t[1] ).dump = function( self )  print "<Foo>"  end
for _, v in ipairs( t ) do  v:dump( )  end
```

the first version will print

```
<Foo>
<Foo>
<Foo>
```

while the second one will print (e.g.)

```
<Foo>
Foo: 0x1267010
Foo: 0x1267120
```

which is clearly different behavior.  So the compiler/… *can not* de-duplicate identical metatables, because other code (that was not yet seen) *might* modify one of the metatables, and then the observed behavior would be different.

▶ This means that if you create multiple (meta)tables, they must be kept somewhere.  Storing several tables necessarily uses more memory than storing a single one, so having a table constructor in argument position for the call to `setmetatable` will use more memory than creating a table first and then passing a reference to it in the call.

---

That said, worrying about memory use *should not be your primary concern*.  The semantics / "meaning" / observable behavior of your code are more important.

- If you modify the metatable, should the behavior of *all* "objects" / values change?  Or do you want to determine object types by metatable identity (`getmetatable( x ) == Foo`)?  Then you *must* use a shared metatable (or an equivalent construction).
- If you modify the metatable, should the behavior of only *a single* "object" change?  Then you *must* construct & use separate metatables per "object" / value.
- Only if *you know that you will never modify* the metatable, will not compare metatable references to determine object types, will not …, then these different approaches will show the same externally visible behavior, and only then you are free to choose based on secondary concerns (like memory usage, convenience / code brevity, …).

(In general, needing separately modifiable metatables is *very* rare, so using shared metatables (create first and pass the reference to `setmetatable`) is the usual approach – it saves memory and is nicer for debugging.)

---

Aside: `gcinfo` is *very* old and only returns integer approximations to the amount of memory used.  Use `collectgarbage "count"` instead, and then you'll see a difference.  (It returns kilobytes used, so multiply by 1024 to get bytes.)

Comment: I feel like that didn't really answer the question, though. A bigger meta table will take more memory, yeah, obviously. But I was asking about setmetatable() and if there is a significant difference between passing the meta table by reference or in-line.

Comment: It did answer the question ("yes, creating new tables for everything will eat more memory"), but it seems there's something about the semantics of Lua that you haven't understood yet. So I've expanded the answer based on guesswork about what that might be. Does that help?

Comment: (The comments in your code show the same "thought bug" – it should be "Passing the meta table by reference" vs. "**Creating** the table in-line" (not "Passing … in-line".) If you now understand why, your question should answer itself.)

Comment: @Forivin In response to your edit ("When you call `setmetatable` […] will that write a complete copy […or] just store a simple reference?") which I just noticed: Tables (and full userdata) have a slot that can store a reference to a table which is then used as the metatable for that value, so it's the latter. (The [next-to-last paragraph of §2.1](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.1) suggests that but it's not made explicit anywhere else. Also see source on [table](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lobject.h.html#Table), [userdata](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lobject.h.html#Udata).)